# PHP decimal value printing issue

Tags: php, output, decimal

I decoded this json array with json_decode function;

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.00000097,"Ask":0.00000100,"Last":0.00000100}}
```

Then, I tried to echo "Bid" value, php prints this like;

```
'9.7E-7'
```

My PHP Code;

```
$orders = file_get_contents("php://input");
$orders = json_decode($orders, true);
$market = str_replace(" ","",$orders["orders"]["sell"]["market"]);
$price = file_get_contents("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=".$market);
$price = json_decode($price, true);
$finalprice = (double)$price["result"]["Bid"];
echo $finalprice;
```

Output;

```
'9.7E-7'
```

I want to print;

```
0.00000097
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo number_format($finalPrice, 8);
```